# Defining a function that treats input as two unordered lists

Tags: functions, function-construction, argument-patterns

I have a function f2 I'd like to code into Mathematica with the property that it takes in two lists, treats those lists as unordered, and maps to a symbolic value.

If I were instead using a function f1 that takes in a single unordered list, then I would use...

```
SetAttributes[f1, Orderless];
```

and Mathematica would correctly recognize (for example) f1[a,b] = f1[b,a] and correctly simplify expressions as such. What I'd like is some means by which I can ensure Mathematica recognizes (for example) f2[a,b][c,d] = f2[b,a][c,d] = f2[a,b][d,c] = f2[b,a][d,c]. The resulting symbolic expressions will eventually have a,b,c,d and so-on set to non-negative integers. My specific application requires variable list lengths.

**Q: Is there a way to symmetrize both input channels of the function?** Or perhaps by instead writing

```
f2[{a,b}][{c,d}]
```

or

```
f2[{a,b},{c,d}]
```

**is there a way to tell Mathematica that it should treat the inputs as unordered lists?**

Thank you for your time. Best wishes.

...

**Edit (for further clarity):** As a concrete example, I want a means by which I can write out something like...

```
f2[{a,b},{c,d}] * g1[x] + f2[{a,b},{d,c}] * g2[x] + f2[{b,a},{c,d}] * g3[x]
```

that Mathematica correctly reduces to,

```
f2[{a,b},{c,d}] * ( g1[x] + g2[x] + g3[x] )
```

Much in the style of how I might manipulate the f1[...] described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an auxiliary head to handle the orderless attribute? For example:

```
SetAttributes[s, Orderless];

expr = f2[{a,b},{c,d}] g1[x]+f2[{a,b},{d,c}] g2[x]+f2[{b,a},{c,d}] g3[x] /. List -> s;
expr //Factor
```

> f2[s[a, b], s[c, d]] (g1[x] + g2[x] + g3[x])

You could dress up the head `s` with a format:

```
MakeBoxes[s[a__], form_] ^:= RowBox[{"(", RowBox@BoxForm`MakeInfixForm[{a}, ",", form], ")"}]
```

The above output then looks like:

```
expr //Factor
```

> f2[(a, b), (c, d)] (g1[x] + g2[x] + g3[x])

Comment: Thank you! This will do the trick, and the dressing is a welcome bonus. :)

Comment: How did this get accepted, but not upvoted and zero? +1 from here...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html):

```
ClearAll[f2, f]
f2[{OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, b_]}, {OrderlessPatternSequence[c_, d_]}] :=
   f[{a, b}, {c, d}]

Equal[f2[{a, b}, {c, d}], f2[{b, a}, {c, d}], f2[{a, b}, {d, c}], f2[{b, a}, {d, c}]]
```

> True

```
Simplify[f2[{a, b}, {c, d}]*g1[x] + f2[{a, b}, {d, c}]*g2[x] + f2[{b, a}, {c, d}]*g3[x]]
```

> f[{a, b}, {c, d}] (g1[x] + g2[x] + g3[x])

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! If I understand your answer correctly, this would be a method of mapping a symbol to a new symbol, and its that mapping which would possess unordered arguments. Is there a way to implement this behavior while maintaining the same variable name (like f1 in my example)? The symbolic calculation I'm doing will proceed in several stages wherein multiple instances of the function f2 will be combined and where each instance has a different combination of arguments. As such, it'd be convenient if the same variable could retain these properties throughout the calculation.

Comment: In other words, I want to treat the function as a symbol in its own right, and only map it to values at the end of the computation.

Comment: @SineOfPsi,  you mean `ClearAll[f1];
f1[{OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, b__]}][{OrderlessPatternSequence[c_, 
    d__]}] := {a, b, c, d} (* or your choice of rhs expression*)`?

Comment: @klgr I've added additional details to my original post to clarify what I'm looking for. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your answer, but it's not clear to me how your proposed solution could be used in the way I desire.

Comment: @SineOfPsi, please see the updated version.

Comment: @klgr Thank you! This is closer. If it could maintain the name "f2" rather than mapping to a new variable, that'd be fantastic. The issue is I'll be adding multiple versions of f2 with potentially-different inputs.

Example: your code would evaluate

    f2[{a1, b1}, {c1, d1}] - f2[{a2, b2}, {c2, d2}]

to

    f[{a1, b1}, {c1, d1}] - f[{a2, b2}, {c2, d2}]

If I then performed a replacement on this,

    % /. {a1 -> 1, b1 -> 1, c1 -> 1, d1 -> 0, a2 -> 1, b2 -> 1, c2 -> 0, 
  d2 -> 1}

I would get

    -f[{1, 1}, {0, 1}] + f[{1, 1}, {1, 0}]

but I'd like it to return zero.